# How to find the find reason for a python daemon process dying?

Tags: python, daemon, python-daemon

I've got a daemon implemented in python using the [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) library.

The daemon appears to periodically die (or is killed) however, where periodically varies from one day to several months.

I've tried to find the reason for the daemon dying by catching exceptions, logging them to a file, and mailing them to me.  The daemon part of my script looks roughly like:

```
import daemon

context = daemon.DaemonContext(
    working_directory='/foo/',
    pidfile=lockfile.FileLock('/foo/foo.pid')
)

try:
    with context:
        do_stuff()
except Exception, e:
    log_exception_to_file(e)
    mail_exeption_to_me(e)
```

I've had quite a few exceptions logged and mailed to me, so I know the code generally works.

For the majority of cases, I get nothing, and a watchdog script alerts me to the fact that the daemon is no longer running.  Is there some way I can find out or track why the daemon is either dying or being killed?

Comment: Is your daemon using paramiko ? because we had such a problem before and we have a workaround.

Comment: You can setup some custom signal handlers and log signals into file. It's not full solution but can point you what is going on there. On the other hand you can run it under debuger or with strace attached

Comment: It's not using paramiko I'm afraid.  I thought about running it through a debugger/strace, problem is that it often stays running for several months before dying, so I need a fairly lightweight way of finding out what happened just before it died.

Comment: Check you disabled the OOM killer on Linux, could be a reason. Also make sure you get core files in case it crashes fatally. Try to catch BaseException too and log it before re-raising, so you get silly bugs like some code raising SystemExit() when you don't expect it. Installing some custom signal handler can help too. The strace solution can work, just pipe the strace output through some other process that just keeps the last hour of logs and throws away the rest.

Comment: Could either log_exception_to_file or mail_exeption (or mail_exception)_to_me throw an exception?

Comment: That's possible - I'll add some code to check for that.

Answer (score 2):

While you are mailing stuff, check the memory consumption. Maybe it has a memory leak and dies when it consumes all available RAM. The `resource` module will let the app find out its maxrss, ixrss, idrss, and isrss and if you log those once every 5 minutes or so, it should be obvious whether or not there is a memory leak happening.